# htaccess - map all query parameters to a simple path/URI without params -- RewriteCond / RewriteRule / mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like htaccess to take

```
image.svg?a=1&b=2
```

And map it to

```
image--a-1--b-2.svg
```

Where **a** and **b** could be any variable, and there could be more parameters too, eg. **a**, **b** and **c** etc.

This very simplistic example would work for one parameter, but not multiple/dynamic:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=(.*)
RewriteRule ^image.svg$  /image--a-%1.svg?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]+)=([^&]*)&*(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.svg$  $1--%1-%2.svg?%3 [NC,L]
```

This solution uses the fact, that rewrite will restart its filter work, when a change has occured, so cycling through all `key=value` pairs.

We

1. separate the (1)key (2)value (3)'rest of QUERY_STRING'
2. prepare the new REQUEST_URI with the extended file name `$1--%1-%2.svg` and concatenate with `?` the shortened QUERY_STRING `%3` that contains the remaining attributes.
3. `[L]`Leave (and so restart) rewrite, to grab the next set from the QUERY_STRING

The last cycle will leave an empty QUERY_STRING, dropping the final `?`. As the QUERY_STRING is empty the loop ends.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that is absolutely beautiful 